# Ember 2.x DS and relationship update

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got an Ember 2.x web app that needs to get data with hasMany relationships : Many "sites" that have many "servers" and many "clients".

```
//Site model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ''}),
  servers: DS.hasMany('server'),
  clients: DS.hasMany('client')
})

//Server model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ip: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: '0.0.0.0'})
  alive: DS.attr('boolean'),
  site: DS.belongsTo('site')
})

//Client model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ip: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: '0.0.0.0'})
  alive: DS.attr('boolean'),
  sites: DS.hasMany('site')
});
```

To fetch my the content, I do something like this :

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('client').then(() => {
    console.info('clients : OK');
    return this.store.findAll('server');
  }).then(() => {
    console.info('servers : OK');
    return this.store.findAll('site');
  }).then((sites) => {
    console.info('sites : OK');
    return sites;
  });
}
```

That's, OK, everything is downloaded and appears on screen as expected.

My app have a Socket.IO client that receive some simple notification telling it that it should reload all "servers" (since the "alive" values have been updated). So I simply execute a findAll('servers'), since I only want to update the servers :

```
this.socket.on('reload-servers', () => {
  that.store.findAll('servers');
});
```

Chrome's Ember data inspector is updated with the new values but not my "sites" content in the web page.

My question is : Why ? I suppose the solution is not as magical as I was expected it to be but after many hours of research, I'm still not able to do it.

I'm not sure to it's the right way to do it neither. I've try many searches on google, but only found examples for Ember 1 that won't work with Ember 2 or that suggest to reload everything.

Comment: where do you fetch your content as described? In the route model hook? This doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: I first fetch the content from model(). I've corrected the code above. I've forgotten to write the "return sites;" line. This part is doing what I'm expected it to do. But maybe you're telling me it's a bad design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using a better code architecture.

I can't post any code example since I've change many things. All I can tell about this is that I'm now using a service which performs the findAll requests and has some computed properties and observers for my vars.

I inject this service in each component that needs to use the fetched datas or the computed values. Everything is now just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per docs - "*findAll asks the adapter's findAll method to find the records for the given type, and return a promise that will be resolved once the server returns the values. The promise will resolve into all records of this type present in the store, even if the server only returns a subset of them.*"

Can you please try something like:

```
return this.store.findAll('servers').then(function(servers){
   return servers;
  });
```

Comment: I've tried, but : The first return can't be done since it's inside a socket io event callback. Returning the 'then' value is still returning a promise with the same resolve answer.